# Or-tools routing nodes vs indices

Tags: or-tools

Can someone please point me to the part in the documentation explaining the difference between nodes and indices? I'm going over code that was written by someone else and it seems to use nodes and indices interchangeably. Also, when I apply `NodeToIndex` or `IndexToNode` on a variable, the value does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the underlying constraint programming model of routing problems, each stop is exactly visited once. Each stop is a index. The routing library allows several vehicles to start and end at a stop. This causes a conflict because a stop may be visited by several vehicles. In ortools this conflict is resolved by creating dummy indices for nodes that are visited by several vehicles. Hence there may be several indicies that are map to the same node. The depot is a typical example.

This page about the auxillary graph helped me: https://acrogenesis.com/or-tools/documentation/user_manual/manual/tsp/model_behind_scenes.html#the-auxiliary-graph

Answer (score 1):

Please read: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing

indices are internal object belonging to the solver, nodes are linked to the distance matrix and the user visits.